# Why am I getting error "unsupported_grant_type"

Tags: c#, authentication, asp.net-web-api, access-token, .net-4.8

I am learning **Token Based Authentication in Web API.**

I have an ASP.NET Web API application and a Windows Forms application. Dot net framework version is "4.8.1". From Windows Forms application I am trying to send a request to get an authentication token. Here is code

```
private void TestButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient();

    HttpRequestMessage httpRequestMessage = new HttpRequestMessage
    {
        Method = HttpMethod.Post,
        RequestUri = new Uri(@"http://localhost:62986/Token"),
        Content = new StringContent(
            $"username:user\npassword:1234\ngrant_type:password")
    };

    HttpResponseMessage httpResponseMessage = httpClient
            .SendAsync(httpRequestMessage).Result;

    richTextBox1.Text = string.Empty;
    richTextBox1.Text += ((int)httpResponseMessage.StatusCode).ToString() + "\n";
    richTextBox1.Text += httpResponseMessage.ReasonPhrase + "\n";
    richTextBox1.Text += httpResponseMessage.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
}
```

In return I am getting

```
400
Bad Request
{"error":"unsupported_grant_type"}
```

**What am I doing wrong?**

I followed [this demo](https://dotnettutorials.net/lesson/token-based-authentication-web-api/)

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned in the demo, you should provide the content type (`x-www-form-urlencoded`) for your request.

Comment: Yeah. I have found the solution already. I will post my own answer as soon as I have ample time. Thanks for your response.